# Replace word in google charts from my php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have script that show stats from my 7 txt files in specific folder, which serach words in txt files "all_user" and "amount".

In google charts in legend I see all_user and amount but I want replace thats words to for exmaple: all_user = USER , Amount = xxx. I don`t know how do that.

Could you help me ?

This i my script:

```
$znajdz_slowo_kluczowe = 'all_user;amount';
$limit_najnowszych_plikow = 7;
$katalog_z_plikami_txt = 'logs';

$dir = $katalog_z_plikami_txt?:'.';
$pliki = glob($dir.'/*.txt');
natsort($pliki);
$pliki1 = array_reverse($pliki);

if ($limit_najnowszych_plikow>0) $pliki1 = array_slice($pliki, 0, 
$limit_najnowszych_plikow);
$znajdz_slowo_kluczowe_tablica = explode(';', $znajdz_slowo_kluczowe);
$znajdz_slowo_kluczowe_tablica = 
array_unique($znajdz_slowo_kluczowe_tablica);


$opisy = array_merge(['Dni tygodnia'], $znajdz_slowo_kluczowe_tablica);


$dane[] = $opisy;
foreach($pliki as $plik) {
if (!preg_match('/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/', $plik, $matches)) continue;
$data = $matches[1].'-'.$matches[2].'-'.$matches[3];
$pakiet = [$data];
$s = file_get_contents($plik);
foreach($znajdz_slowo_kluczowe_tablica as $slowo)
{
array_push($pakiet, substr_count($s, $slowo));
                        }
$dane[] = $pakiet;  
}
?>
<script>
var dane_do_wykresuu = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($dane);?>');
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dane_do_wykresu);
var options = {
colors: ['#008744', '#0057e7', '#d62d20', '#ffa700', '#000000',],
chart: {
title: '',
subtitle: '',
}
};
var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('wykres'));
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));                             
}
</script>

Maybe use function array in php :
$arr = array(
"all_user" => "word1",
"amount" => "word2",
); 
but where do add this at script
```